# How to import Windows DDK headers into IDA?

Tags: ida, windows, driver

Currently I'm reversing a Windows driver, and there are a lot of structs IDA doesn't automatically recognize, which means I have to import them manually by parsing C header files.

However, there are way too many nested structs/unions and I have to modify each one so IDA can parse it correctly. They go so deep, they make me spend more time on adding structs rather than actually reversing.

Is there any way of doing this?

I did try parsing the file I need with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, but IDA doesn't understand stuff like e.g. `#include`s and errors, making this option impossible to use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`View->Open subviews->Type Libraries` (<kbd>Shift-F11</kbd>), right click, `Load Type Library...`, `wdk8_km`.

Answer (score 7):

Create an empty file, include whatever headers you want, add a `DriverEntry` and compile with debug symbols enabled and no optimization. Now load the test driver into IDA. If done correctly, All types should be available.
You should be able to export all types via `File->Produce File->Dump typeinfo to IDC file...` then load the script back `File->Script File...`.

Comment: Very smart trick! This time I will go with Igor's answer but you definitely have my upvote, as that could work even if IDA doesn't support the type library I need.