# How to adjust function type/call parameters to custom structs in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, binary-analysis

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a function in `IDA Pro` that was originally identified by `IDA` as such (I was able to rename it into `Device_CreateCloseIoControl`):

[image]

but I know that this function was originally compiled as this:

[image]

where `DEVICE_OBJECT` and `IRP` structs are defined in `wdm.h` from `Windows Driver Kit`.

So I'm curious, is there a way to rename this function to make `IDA` use those custom types? (Included in a specific header file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to do the following:

1. Define or import structures involved in function definition if not defined yet. You can add a structure via Structures window (View-->Open Subviews-->Structures, or <kbd>Shift-F9</kbd>) , import the header file via File-->Load file-->Parse C header file, or <kbd>Ctrl-F9</kbd> (this will also import typedefs if needed) or use a type library as described in [How to import Windows DDK headers into IDA?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13175/how-to-import-windows-ddk-headers-into-ida) .
2. After that you should locate cursor at the function definition, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and enter C function prototype as it stated in the function definition.

Good luck.